# Netbeans indentation issue in diff tools

Tags: svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn, diff, bitbucket

I am using Netbeans with bitbucket in the past I was using with tortoise svn and Beyond compare as a diff tool. Whenever I am using a diff tools I have some wrong indentations which appeared only on the diff tool I am using, in the IDE itself the code was indented correctly.

Do somebody know this issue and can give me a reference for a solution to this problem?
I'm pretty sure it is linked to Netbeans as I was switching diff tools, and the problem remain the same.